# Infinite Loop occurs when using main function

Tags: python, while-loop, infinite-loop, program-entry-point

Was playing with loops to prepare for my incoming project. and I found infinite loop when using while loop + main function

```
#1
def choice(name):
    while True:
        if name == "Eat"
            print("I don't want to eat now")
        elif name == "Drink"
            print("NOPE")
        else:
            print("o.O?")

def main():
    name = input("Eat or Drink ? :")
    choice(name)
main()

#2
while True:
    name = input("Eat or Drink ? :")
    if name == "Eat"
        print("I don't want to eat now")
    elif name == "Drink"
        print("NOPE")
    else:
        print("o.O?")
```

Number 2 doesn't generate infinite loops despite I don't have any return

But when I use Number 1, so that I can use the name variable into  different functions in future, it generates infinite loop.

Can I know the reason why it is happening? and how do I fix it while keeping name variable nested in main function?

Thanks!

Comment: A `while(True)` loop will run forever until you either `return` a value or `break` out of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because in version #2 you read input from console on every loop iteration (this line: `name = input("Eat or Drink ? :")`). So it is still an infinite loop, but this time it waits on every iteration until you provide some input.

You can fix it by just adding this line: `name = input("Eat or Drink ? :")` to your `choice` function or use:

```
for i in range(100):
    ...
```

If you want to limit the number of iterations.

EDIT:
Ok, so take `while True` from `choice` function and put it into main, like this:

```
def main():
     while True:
          name = input("Eat or Drink ? :")
          choice(name)
          ... other functions using name
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But the thing is I need to use my name variable into different functions in future so that it needs to stay under main function.